# rpm -Uvh - How to replace modified config file

Tags: linux, rpm

*The question is a duplicate from Stackoverflow site*

I upgrade rpm package with `rpm -Uvh` command.

Original and new configuration file is the same, but current file on disk has been changed.

This situation described in [Original file = X, Current file = Y, New file = X](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-upgrade.html)

Due to delivered fixes in a new rpm file I want to overwrite this configuration file anyway. Is there way to do it?

The configuration file appear in `%config` section of rpm spec.

`--replacefiles`, `--replacepkgs` options don't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove config file prior to upgrade, and then upgrade. List of config files you can get by

```
rpm -qplc package.rpm
```

and then - remove/rename all, and upgrade - it'll create a new one config files.

"correct" way is a bit other - in spec file don't tag config file which should be replaced as "%config(noreplace)" - but it must be done when package is build.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it would be a good idea always remove/rename configuration files on Production system, since its not all the time X-Y-X situation I described in my question.

Comment: it's not good idea. but - rpm's aren't interactive - so you have only three possibilites:
- replace config file (always) - this it the same as mv/remove old file and replace with a new one
- save config file and create new one as .rpmnew
- automaticly merge (in %post section of rpm) old config with a new one - but it's dangerous, because it's easy to destroy file - it's usefull only when you only need to add some sections to file or replace variables.